# Como hago que mi aplicación node trabaje de forma continua?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estoy empezando en node y para iniciar mi proyecto en la web estoy usando el comando `nodemon` que ejecuta el js inicial de mi proyecto, pero esto solo es para etapa de desarrollo, ya finalice mi aplicación pero no se como hacer que mi aplicación corra continuamente, necesito que este activa mientras mi pc este prendido y no tenga que ejecutar ese script todo el tiempo, adicional, yo vengo de trabajar con XAMPP, pero con node no se como hacer que mi app local se pueda ver en la web desde otros dispositivos que esten conectados a mi misma red local.

Comment: Tu pregunta se puede basar en opiniones. Asi que, mi opinión es que revises [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever), una librería para realizar lo que pretendes. Saludos

Comment: PM2 sería una buena opción

Comment: Y cualquiera de estas dos me permitiría ver mi app desde otro dispositivo? Y como se realizaría esto? Por lo que lei de forever básicamente es el simil de apache, verdad?

Comment: Pues algo así. La idea es que al reiniciar tu servidor (por cualquier motivo) se ejecute el script que levanta tu servidor Node. En cuanto a cómo lo implementas, para eso está la documentación.

Comment: Así como dice  @Aprendiz PM2 es una buena opción, pero según entiendo es sólo para plataformas Linux.

Respecto a Windows hay maneras de dejar el "run" de NodeJS como servicio y añadirlo al arranque del SO.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que tu aplicacion node se vea desde otros dispositivos conectados a la red en modo WebApp.

Puedes usar la librería expressjs.
(casi se pareceria a un PHP, lo digo porque vienes de XAMPP)

echale un ojo al hello word de expressjs. (te pego el ejemplo aqui)

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Para mas info puedes consultar la documentación de expressjs.